# "You will want to..." vs. "you will be wanting to..."

Tags: difference, stative-verbs, future-continuous

Could you tell me what the difference in meaning between *you will want to* and *you will be wanting to* is? For example in the ninth episode of the second season of *Rick and Morty*, an alien said the following?

> Of course, **you’ll be wanting to be gone** from here by sundown.

Apparently he used in the sense of giving advice. How this sentence is different from the one below?

> Of course, **you’ll want to be gone** from here by sundown.

Comment: Both are fine, and they mean the same thing. Make life easier for yourself and others by always choosing the ***simpler*** verb tense if it makes no difference. That's what most native speakers do most of the time - *particularly* native ***Anglophones***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"You'll be wanting to do x"** can be patronizing (mean) or kind. And it depends on the tone and context in which it is said.

That is the pragmatic difference (pragmatics is a branch of linguistics).

the branch of linguistics dealing with language in use and the contexts in which it is used, including such matters as deixis, the taking of turns in conversation, text organization, presupposition, and implicature. [google dictionary]

It is more emphatic than "**You'll want to be done by tomorrow**".

Also, bear this in mind:

- He's wanting to get the car fixed.

Generally, verbs of emotion are not used in the continuous tenses. However, when they are, they take on special meaning.  "He's wanting to do x" is more emphatic/emotional than He wants to do x. It makes it seem like the emotion associated with want is almost an action verb.